# How to check if ElementRef contains a mat-icon node in angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-directive, angular-template

I am trying to switch the hello component back to using the `viewMode` template by clicking outside of the component. However, my method as shown below is not working. When the mat-icon is clicked, the contains method return false even though it is part of the component. How to write the handler to check that the click was not fired by mat-icon or the text?

```html
// app.component.html
<ng-template #viewMode>
    This is {{ data }}.
    <mat-icon (click)="child.toggleMode()">create</mat-icon>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #editMode>
    <form [formGroup]="simpleForm">
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  </form>
        <mat-icon (click)="child.toggleMode()">done</mat-icon>
</ng-template>
<app-hello #child [viewModeTemplate]="viewMode" [editModeTemplate]="editMode" (update)="handleUpdate()">
</app-hello>
```

```js
// app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: string = "42";
  simpleForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.simpleForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.data]
    });
  }

  handleUpdate() {
    this.data = this.simpleForm.value.name;
  }
}
```

```js
// hello.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: "app-hello",
  templateUrl: "./hello.component.html"
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() viewModeTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() editModeTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Output() update = new EventEmitter();

  mode: "view" | "edit" = "view";

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){
  }

  get element(){
    return this.el.nativeElement;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  editModeHandler(event) {
    // not working
    // if (!this.element.contains(event.target)){
    //   this.mode = "view";
    // }
  }


  toggleMode() {
    if (this.mode === "edit") {
      this.mode = "view";
      this.update.next();
    } else {
      this.mode = "edit";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
// hello.component.html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="mode === 'view' ? viewModeTemplate : editModeTemplate">
</ng-container>
```

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsgjcb

Comment: you can ask about `event.target.className`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It bugs out because your `child.toggleNode()` will fire first, since the event bubbles:

1. Event reaches child.
2. Event triggers toggle and swaps templates.
3. Event reaches document.
4. Event checks for contains, but the icon has changed.

If you remove the `child.toggleNode()`, your code will work like expected.

You have to defer the toggling until your HostListener on body triggers. You can do that with RxJS or just a setTimeout. I think the nicest solution would be to remove the HostListener altogether and do this with RxJS:

```
const outsideClick$ = merge(
  fromEvent(this.element, 'click').pipe(map(() => false))
  fromEvent(document.body, 'click').pipe(map(() => true))
).pipe(
  throttleTime(0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Child nodes can be obtained from `element.nativeElement.children`.

For your scenario try the below code:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  editModeHandler(event) {
    let childnodes = this.element.children;
    for(var index in childnodes) {
      console.log(childnodes[index].tagName, event.target.tagName)
      if(childnodes[index].tagName === event.target.tagName){
        this.mode = "view";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Using `tagname`, child node tag can be found.